# Time out dojo BusyButton with function completion

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a BusyButton implemented programmatically in the following way:

```
var printButton = new BusyButton({
    busyLabel: "Impression...",
    label: "Imprimer",
    timeout: 50000,
    onClick: printMap
  }, "print_button_bis").startup();
```

The timeout at 50000 is not always ideal. How can I set the timeout to occur when the function finishes? Is there an easy way to do this when declaring the button, or should this be integrated in the printMap function somehow?

**UPDATE**
Using printButton.cancel() does indeed work the first time, re-enabling the button. However, the button fails to become busy a second time and works essentially like a normal button. printButton.refresh() causes TypeError: printButton.refresh is not a function.

**UPDATE 2**
I've changed my printButton by removing the timeout parameter, as the cancel() function now sucessfully "times out" the busy button.

```
var printButton = new BusyButton({
        busyLabel: "Impression...",
        label: "Imprimer",
        onClick: printMap
      }, "print_button_bis").startup();
```

After a function's completion, I'm re-enabling the busyButton in this way:

```
printButton.cancel();
printButton.makeBusy();
```

However, the makeBusy line keeps the busyButton disabled for a period of time.

Here's all of the code, in case there's something else I'm overlooking:

```
require([
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/dijit/Print",
  "esri/tasks/PrintTemplate",
  "esri/tasks/PrintTask",
  "esri/tasks/PrintParameters",
  "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
  "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters",
  "esri/geometry/Point",
  "esri/SpatialReference",
  "esri/request",
  "esri/config",
  "dijit/registry",
  "dijit/form/ComboBox",
  "dijit/form/Button",
  "dijit/form/CheckBox",
  "dojox/form/BusyButton",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/on"
], function(
  FeatureLayer,
  Print, PrintTemplate,
  PrintTask, PrintParameters,
  GeometryService,
  ProjectParameters,
  Point, SpatialReference,
  esriRequest, esriConfig, registry,
  ComboBox, Button, CheckBox, BusyButton, Memory,
  arrayUtils, dom, on
) {

  var printUrl = "http://ourserver/arcgis/rest/services/TOOLS/Print_Tool/GPServer/Exporter%20une%20carte%20Web";

  esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "http://ourwebserver/Java/proxy.jsp";
  esri.config.defaults.io.timeout = 300000; //60 seconds = 60000

  var scaleCheckBox = new CheckBox({
        checked: false,
        onChange: function (val) {
            //dom.byId('one').innerHTML = val ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
            if (scaleCheckBox.checked) {
              //params.template.preserveScale = true;
              dijit.byId("scale_select").attr("disabled",false);
              console.log("checked");
            }
            else {
              //params.template.preserveScale = false;
              dijit.byId("scale_select").attr("disabled",true);
              console.log("unchecked");
            }
        }
    }, 'scale_check');


  var printButton = new BusyButton({
    busyLabel: "Impression...",
    label: "Imprimer",
    onClick: printMap
  }, "print_button_bis").startup();


  function printMap(){
    var printMap = new esri.tasks.PrintTask(printUrl);
    var params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters();
    var template = new esri.tasks.PrintTemplate();
    document.getElementById("print_status").innerHTML = "Impression en cours...";
    document.getElementById("output_url").innerHTML = "";

    var layout = dojo.byId("printLayoutId");
    var index = layout.selectedIndex;
    var selectedValue_layout = layout.options[index].value;
    var format = dojo.byId("format");
    var index = format.selectedIndex;
    var selectedValue_format = format.options[index].value;

    var lat = window.myMap.extent.getCenter().getLatitude().toFixed(2);
    var long = window.myMap.extent.getCenter().getLongitude().toFixed(2);

    var latLong = "Latitude : " + lat + " - Longitude : " + long;

    var X;
    var Y;

    var rgpfSixSudSR = new SpatialReference ({
      wkid : 3297
    });

    var wgsGCSEightFourSR = new SpatialReference ({
      wkid : 4326
    });

    var geometryService = new GeometryService("http://ourserver/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    var inputPoint = new Point(lat, long, wgsGCSEightFourSR);
    var prjParams = new ProjectParameters ();
    prjParams.geometries = [inputPoint];
    prjParams.outSR = rgpfSixSudSR;

    geometryService.project(prjParams, function (outputpoint) {
      console.log('Conversion completed');
      X = outputpoint[0].x;
      Y = outputpoint[0].y;
    });

    var center = "X : " + X + " - Y : " + Y;



    console.log(latLong);
    console.log(center);


    params.map = window.myMap;

    if (scaleCheckBox.checked) {
      params.template = {
        layout: selectedValue_layout,
        format: selectedValue_format,
        preserveScale: true,
        layoutOptions: {
          customTextElements : [
             {
               centerLatLong: latLong
             }
           ]
         }
      }
      console.log("checked");
    }
    else {
      params.template = {
        layout: selectedValue_layout,
        format: selectedValue_format,
        preserveScale: false,
        layoutOptions: {
          customTextElements : [
             {
               centerLatLong: latLong
             }
           ]

         }
      }
      console.log("unchecked");
    }

    printMap.execute(params, printResult);


    function printResult(result){
      console.log(result.url);
      document.getElementById("print_status").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("output_url").href = result.url;
      document.getElementById("output_url").innerHTML = "Impression";

      var printButton = dijit.byId("print_button_bis");
      printButton.cancel();
      printButton.makeBusy(); //this one does not make it busy (only busy the first time)
      var printWindow = window.open(result.url);

    };
  };

});
```

Comment: If you don't want a timeout you must manually change the status of the button. In your printMap function, when you know that it is safe to enable the button again: `printButton.cancel();` You may also need a `printButton.refresh();`

Comment: @pgianna printButton.cancel() seems to "break" the busy button--no longer becomes busy. This may be where the refresh() comes in, but I'm getting refresh is not a function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cancel() and makeBusy() to programmatically control the state of the button. refresh() is not needed. This is an example:

```js
require(["dojox/form/BusyButton"],
  function(BusyButton) {
  
  var button1 = new BusyButton({
    id: "work",
    busyLabel: "Working...",
    label: "Work",
    onClick: function() {
    button2.cancel();
    }
  }, "placeHolder");
  
  var button2 = new BusyButton({
    id: "stop",
    busyLabel: "Stop",
    label: "Stop",
    onClick: function() {
    button1.cancel();
    }
  }, "placeHolder2");
  button2.makeBusy();

  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<div class="claro">
 <div id="placeHolder"></div>
 <div id="placeHolder2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How come only button2 needs makeBusy() after the cancel?

Comment: It's not after cancel, it's right after construction to start it at a busy state.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake..I still can't get it to work however. Calling makeBusy() after cancel() makes the button stay busy. Not calling makeBusy() after cancel() breaks the busy functionality (second time using the button, the button doesn't become busy). These are called when a print job has finished, and the print job function is called.